# How to add custom timeframe in moving average ribbon indicator in trading view?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, trading, tradingview-api, pine-script-v4

#### Moving average ribbon (built-in indicator)

I want to add a custom timeframe selector for each moving average separately other than the whole script timeframe selector, I want a check/uncheck box for script timeframe selector so that I can switch between the whole script timeframe selector and individual timeframe selector.

Also I use 10D, 21D, 10W, 20W and 40W moving averages so if I can add another check/uncheck box functionality through which I can select to view only 10W,20W and 40W on weekly timeframe and when I switch to daily timeframe it adds 10D, 21D, with 10W,20W and 40W intact on the daily chart. I will add 5th moving average myself.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [nonRepaintingClose](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/concepts/Repainting.html#repainting-request-security-calls) function to not repaint, and Select Higher Timeframe
Something like that

```
f_nonRepaintingSecurity(_sym, _htf, _src) =>
    request.security(_sym, _htf ,_src[barstate.isrealtime ? 1 : 0])[barstate.isrealtime ? 0 : 1]

i_htf1 = input.timeframe  ('','MA #1 HTF')
ma1HTF = f_nonRepaintingSecurity(syminfo.tickerid, i_htf1, 
  ma(ma1_source, ma1_length, ma1_type))
plot(ma1HTF, "MA №1 HTF", color.fuchsia, 3)
```